# Pandas dataframe choose first 5 of x, then first 5 of y, first five of z, etc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

```
Name     Amount
---------------
Alice       100
Bob          50
Charlie     200
Alice        30
Charlie      10
Bob         300 
Charlie      55
Charlie      12
```

Given the above dataframe I want to sort by amount (don't need help here)
and then choose top 5 amounts for each of the persons: the top five amounts spent by Alice, Charlie, etc, and put this into a new dataframe.
All the remaining smaller expenditures will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can use `nlargest()` method:

```
In [12]: top2 = df.groupby('Name').Amount.nlargest(2).reset_index().drop('level_1',1)

In [13]: top2
Out[13]:
      Name  Amount
0    Alice     100
1    Alice      30
2      Bob     300
3      Bob      50
4  Charlie     200
5  Charlie      55
```